# Iframe listen for event in parent document

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to listen for events triggered on the parent document by the parent document from within an `<iframe>`

In the parent window:

```
$(document).on('MyNameSpace.MyEvent', function() {
    console.log('Event received in parent');  
});
$(document).trigger('MyNameSpace.MyEvent');
```

In the iframe:

```
//test1
$(parent.document).on('MyNameSpace.MyEvent', someFunction);
//test2
parent.$(document).on('MyNameSpace.MyEvent', someFunction);

var someFunction = function() {
    console.log('Event received in Iframe');
};
```

Both tests above fail to fire when the event is triggered on the parent document. The console outputs only:

```
Event received in parent
```

How can I achieve the desired behaviour?

### Notes

1. Both iframe and parent are in the same domain.
2. The trigger occurs after user interaction such as a click, after the DOM has fully loaded for both parent and iframe.
3. Legacy browser support is required (IE8+)

Comment: Are page and iframe on same domain?

Comment: Yes, always for this implementation.

Comment: Seems like it should work but i tried it also. Could use postMessage API

Comment: Would love to, but it needs to support legacy browsers...

Comment: IE 8 has postMessage support for iframes, surely you aren't supporting anything older

Comment: My mistake, I didn't realise it was supported. I will look into it, haven't used before - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using :

```
parent.$(parent.document).on('MyNameSpace.MyEvent', someFunction);
```

The above solutions works if parent supports jQuery.

From the current iframe to listen in parent, you have to use 'parent.$'. Since this is an event in parent iframe, you have to use 'parent.document'.

Comment: Please add some explanation to this answer on, why one has to use it.